# How do you get equals() working with Hibernate entities when lazy=true?

Tags: hibernate, proxy, lazy-loading, equals

For some reason when lazy=true on all my entities, the equals() method does not work correctly when one side is a lazily-loaded entity and the other side is a normal entity. Here's an example:

```
if(activeTask.getTask().equals(task)) {...}
```

In this case, the activeTask's task will be a proxy while the right side will be a regular one. The equals() will fail. To fix this problem, I often do things like this:

```
if(activeTask.getTask().getId() == task.getId()) {...}
```

This works, but it's not ideal. I'd rather use my equals() method.

Does anyone have a nice solution to this problem? It really adds to the application's level of noise to have to think about stuff like this.

If I say lazy=false, I don't have to deal with proxy's, and so equals() will work. But this has a very negative impact on performance.

It is just not cool to have to say, "equals() works in all cases, except when you use proxies... then equals() is not reliable."

Comment: It is 2018. I'm using Hibernate 5.2 and still seeing the same error. I solved it by disabling lazy as you mentioned. The other workarounds seem a bit fragile. Also, I don't want to overload .equals() with a ton of logic.

Comment: Hava a look here: https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/hopefully-the-final-article-about-equals-and-hashcode-for-jpa-entities-with-db-generated-ids/

Answer (score 8):

I realize this is an old question, but it's still unanswered and people might stumble upon it.

I had the same problem a few days ago. In the project we use an abstract base class `BasicEntityType`, which has just an ID and equals is implemented in said base class:

```
@Override
public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }

    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }

    Class<?> objClass = HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy(obj);
    if (this.getClass() != objClass) {
        return false;
    }

    if (id == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return id.equals(((BasicEntityType) obj).getId());
}
```

There are two critical parts in this code:

- First: Do not check directly for class equality, it might not work with the given object.
- Second: All properties of the given object have to be accessed by using methods. Or you could unwrap the actual object.

Comment: You should not use the database ID in equals and hashcode when using hibernate. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode

Comment: HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy(obj) doesn't work with inheritance because it calls to org.hibernate.proxy.LazyInitializer.getPersistentClass() instead of org.hibernate.proxy.LazyInitializer.getImplementation()